# How to override Scroll?

Tags: android, scroll, android-nestedscrollview

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/left_col"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The height of `recyclerView` is predefined by the code and is equal to the height of the screen of the device. The idea is that the user does not feel 2 vertical scrolls on the screen (that is, for him to look like 1 scrolled).
How to make it so that when the `textView1` is smoothly scrolling the content before the beginning of `recyclerView`, stopped and then scrolled passed inside `recyclerView`?

Comment: Similar behavior will be if I set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` on RecycleView, but in this case it will not be possible to use recycle and will receive OutOfMemory on big data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have some options:

1. If you do not want to scroll outside of `RecyclerView`, change `NestedScrollView` to another kind of `ViewGroup`, like `LinearLayout`.
2. If you want to have a continuos vertical scroll, you can disable programatically using `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

Also, your recyclerView will not have the dinamically screen size, because you're using a static height `android:layout_height="500dp"`

Comment: You did not understand me. I want the content to scroll to the beginning of the position of RecycledViev and stop. The whole subsequent impulse was transmitted to RecyclerViev and he scrolled the elements.

Comment: And I override height of RecycleView by code. The value indicated in the layout does not mean anything.

Comment: Alright, you only want to scroll inside RecyclerView? So change `NestedScrollView `, or you will have two scrolls on the screen.

Comment: I already explained to you 2 times and you did not understand. Please answer the question. How to override Scroll? For more information, I can explain this only in Russian.

Comment: I already answered that too, you have two options to continue that, read my first answer again.

Comment: No, you answered a completely different question. Here the question was: How to override scrolling? A response is awaited that contains the MotionEvent processing.